# Finding the differences between tables with same schema, with changes and original values in same output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, each with the same schema.

The first one (or `OldDataTable` from here on) looks like this:

```
| PlantID | OutletId  | BusinessTypeID | TradeChannelID |
|---------|-----------|----------------|----------------|
| I000    | 500113730 |              1 |              8 |
| I000    | 500113772 |              1 |             12 |
| I000    | 500113819 |              1 |             40 |
| I000    | 500113821 |              1 |              8 |
| I000    | 500113848 |              1 |              7 |
```

The second one (or `NewDataTable` from here on) looks like this:

```
| PlantID | OutletId  | BusinessTypeID | TradeChannelID |
|---------|-----------|----------------|----------------|
| I000    | 500113730 |              2 |              5 |
| I000    | 500113772 |              1 |             12 |
| I000    | 500113819 |              1 |             40 |
| I000    | 500113821 |              1 |              8 |
| I000    | 500113848 |              1 |              7 |
```

You can see, there are some differences. For a given `OutletId` (500113730), the `BusinessTypeID` and `TradeChannelID` changed in the `NewDataTable` as opposed to the `OldDataTable`.

I can't figure out a query that accomplishes what I am looking for. I need have a query that produces an output that shows the `OutletID` that changed and then what changed, along with its original value. Given the two examples above, the result should look like this:

```
| PlantID | Change_PlantID | OutletID  | Change_OutletID | BusinessTypeID | Change_BusinessTypeID | TradeChannelID | Change_TradeChannelID |
|---------|----------------|-----------|-----------------|----------------|-----------------------|----------------|-----------------------|
| I000    |                | 500113730 |                 |              1 |                     2 |              8 |                     5 |
```

Couple things to note:

The application will not always know what was changed, if anything was changed. The output only shows the `OutletId`s that changed.

Comment: A couple of questions: is OutletId a primary key?; which are the attributes that can change?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to output to CSV and then use Beyond Compare.

Comment: OutletID is not a primary key on these tables, though they are unique values. I do not have access to change that, but it is what it is.

Comment: will NewDataTable have inserts/additions or just changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy enough to join the two tables together, using a constraint that checks for anything different:

```
SELECT
    old.PlantID
    ,old.OutletID
    ,old.BusinessTypeID
    ,new.BusinessTypeID AS Change_BusinessTypeID
    ,old.TradeChannelID
    ,new.TradeChannelID AS Change_TradeChannelID
FROM
    OldDataTable old
FULL OUTER JOIN
    NewDataTable new
    ON
    old.PlantID = new.PlantID
    AND
    old.OutletID = new.OutletID
WHERE
    (
        old.BusinessTypeID <> new.BusinessTypeID
        OR
        old.TradeChannelID <> new.TradeChannelID
    )
```

What this won't do is hide the old/new pairs of one column that didn't change while another column in the same row did, but you could easily add some checks in the SELECT list (e.g. `SELECT CASE WHEN old.column <> new.column THEN old.column END`).

Update - here's what the statement might look like if you want to handle the case where only what changed *per column* is included in the results:

```
SELECT
    old.PlantID
    ,old.OutletID
    ,(CASE WHEN old.BusinessTypeID <> new.BusinessTypeID THEN old.BusinessTypeID END) AS BusinessTypeID
    ,(CASE WHEN old.BusinessTypeID <> new.BusinessTypeID THEN new.BusinessTypeID END) AS Change_BusinessTypeID
    ,(CASE WHEN old.TradeChannelID <> new.TradeChannelID THEN old.TradeChannelID END) AS TradeChannelID
    ,(CASE WHEN old.TradeChannelID <> new.TradeChannelID THEN new.TradeChannelID END) AS Change_TradeChannelID
FROM
    OldDataTable old
FULL OUTER JOIN
    NewDataTable new
    ON
    old.PlantID = new.PlantID
    AND
    old.OutletID = new.OutletID
WHERE
    (
        old.BusinessTypeID <> new.BusinessTypeID
        OR
        old.TradeChannelID <> new.TradeChannelID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple version for you. You can change the CASE statement(s) as you need to to benefit what output you wish (e.g. use bit fields, etc)... If you wish to return all rows, changed or not, just REM out the WHERE clause.

Hope it assists,

```
DECLARE @OldDataTable AS TABLE (PlantID nvarchar(20), OutletId nvarchar(20), BusinessTypeID int,TradeChannelID int )
DECLARE @NewDataTable AS TABLE (PlantID nvarchar(20), OutletId nvarchar(20), BusinessTypeID int,TradeChannelID int )

INSERT INTO @OldDataTable
VALUES
('I000','500113730',1,8)
,('I000','500113772',1,12)
,('I000','500113819',1,40)  
,('I000','500113821',1,8) 
,('I000','500113848',1,7) 


INSERT INTO @NewDataTable
VALUES
('I000','500113730',2,5)
,('I000','500113772',1,12)
,('I000','500113819',3,40)
,('I000','500113821',1,9)
,('I000','500113848',1,7)

SELECT      a.PlantID
            ,a.OutletId
            ,a.BusinessTypeID
            ,a.TradeChannelID
            ,b.BusinessTypeID
            ,b.TradeChannelID
            ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN a.BusinessTypeID <> b.BusinessTypeID THEN 'BusinessTypeID' ELSE '' END 
         + '   ' + CASE WHEN a.TradeChannelID <> b.TradeChannelID THEN 'TradeChannelID' ELSE '' END)) as ChangeType
FROM        @OldDataTable a
INNER JOIN  @NewDataTable b ON a.OutletId = b.OutletId
WHERE       a.BusinessTypeID <> b.BusinessTypeID
    OR      a.TradeChannelID <> b.TradeChannelID
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a CTE to find the differences, then use the differences in a join back to both tables to find the old and new values.

This will need to change if you need to find which of the OldDataTable records currently don't exist.

```
--Find which records are different between the tables.
--Note, this will show duplicates only once and will not take into consideration additions to OldDataTable.
;with GetDiff as (
select PlantID , OutletId  , BusinessTypeID , TradeChannelID 
from @NewDataTable
except 
select PlantID , OutletId  , BusinessTypeID , TradeChannelID  
from @OldDataTable
)

--Join to the CTE. Note: Use a left join for OldDataTable in case a new record appears in NewDataTable
select g.PlantID, g.OutletId, n.BusinessTypeID, o.BusinessTypeID as Change_BusinessTypeID, n.TradeChannelID, o.TradeChannelID as Change_TradeChannelID
from GetDiff G
join @NewDataTable n on g.OutletId = n.OutletId
left join @OldDataTable o on g.OutletId = o.OutletId
```

Comment: The best solution is to add a surrogate primary key to the table. Finding changes is much easier that way. Alternatively, add a trigger to the table, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this using `PIVOT` to get 'attribute' and 'value' columns, then `JOIN`ing `WHERE` the attributes match and the values differ, across a specified range of 'monitored' columns.

Sadly I can't remember exactly what I did or get at the code right now, but this should give you enough to work with to implement your own variant of this.

(This was actually in a `TRIGGER`, comparing the metatables `deleted` and `inserted` to get a changelog - but it would apply to physical tables too.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to be able to determine whether a differing column (across the two sets) indicuates a revised row or a different row. Just eyeballing the data,

| I000    | 500113730 |              1 |              8 |

Is clearly a change from

| I000    | 500113730 |              2 |              5 |

But is

| I000    | 500113730 |              1 |              8 |

A change from

| I000    | 500113821|              1 |              8 |

Or a new and different row (as it appears to be in your set)? And what do we make of having

| I000    | 500113730 |              1 |              8 |

and

| I000    | 500113821|              1 |              5 |

-- which row is this modified from? What changed—OutletId from 3730 to 3821, or TradeChannelid from 8 to 5? Or both? Do we have to consider how many rows are in each table, or how many columns differ (1, 2, or more) in our sets? Once you know this, you can proceed.

I wrote the above based on my usual tactics for similar situations: ye olde `SELECT… EXCEPT…` statements. Run

```
select *
 from OldDataTable
except select *
 from NewDataTable
```

and

```
select *
 from @NewDataTable
except select *
 from @OldDataTable
```

and each will produce the full row in the first table that is not matched, column for column, in the second table. Well and good, but then you have to join them as per the other answers' join queries, using CTEs, subqueries, or the like. Without the above-discussed keys/identifiers, how do you do that?

Your mileage will vary depending on the actual criteria underlying your data and the desired result set. I recommend messing around with `SELECT… EXCEPT…` and seeing what comes up.